# use generic types in python to refactor code

Tags: refactoring, graphene-python

I have been trying several ways to refactor the following code as these classes are recurring in my app:

```
class CreateRecord(Mutation):
    record = Field(lambda: Unit)

    class Arguments:
        input = CreateInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['createdAt'] = datetime.utcnow()
        # data['createdBy'] = <user>  # TODO: <user> input

        record = UnitModel(**data)
        db_session.add(record)
        db_session.commit()

        return CreateRecord(record=record)


class UpdateRecord(Mutation):
    record = Field(lambda: Unit)

    class Arguments:
        input = UpdateInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['updatedAt'] = datetime.utcnow()
        # data['updatedBy'] = <user>  # TODO: <user> input

        record = db_session.query(UnitModel).filter_by(id=data['id'])
        record.update(data)
        db_session.commit()

        record = db_session.query(UnitModel).filter_by(id=data['id']).first()

        return UpdateRecord(record=record)


class DeleteRecord(Mutation):
    record = Field(lambda: Unit)

    class Arguments:
        input = DeleteInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['deletedAt'] = datetime.utcnow()
        # data['deletedBy'] = <user>  # TODO: <user> input
        data['isDeleted'] = True

        record = db_session.query(UnitModel).filter_by(id=data['id'])
        record.update(data)
        db_session.commit()

        record = db_session.query(UnitModel).filter_by(id=data['id']).first()

        return DeleteRecord(record=record)
```

I was thinking of using generic types but I'm kinda' stuck on how to implement it.  I've tried creating a master class and in the

```
def mutate:
```

method I'd just check if it's a create, update or delete action but I still want to work with generic types before I do that.

Any help is highly appreciated.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this particular problem for myself with a mixin class that includes the following method:

```
from graphene.utils.str_converters import to_snake_case

class MutationResponseMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_operation_type(cls):
        """
        Determine the CRUD type from the mutation class name.
        Uses mutation's class name to determine correct operation.
        ( create / update / delete )
        """
        return to_snake_case(cls.__name__).split('_')[0]
```

This allows me to include a mutation method in the mixin that is shared by create, update, and delete methods and takes conditional action based on value of `get_operation_type`.

I also needed a way to determine the base record from the mixin's mutation (which in your case would be `UnitModel`) so my case I ended up declarding it explicitly as an attribute of each mutation class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I've changed to neo4j with neo4j-graphql extension since...this might help others though...